# Contradicting answers for phase velocity and group velocity of light in a medium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, phase-velocity

The velocity of waves through the medium of refractive index $\mathrm{n}$ is $\sqrt{n / k}$. The group velocity in the medium is

(a) $\frac{1}{3} V_{p}$

(b) $\frac{4}{3} V_{p}$

(c) $\frac{1}{2} V_{p}$

(d) $\frac{2}{3} V_{p}$

That is the question. I tried solving it in two ways and I am getting different answers.I don't know why am I getting two different answers. And I don't know which one is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$ v_p = \frac{\omega} k = \sqrt n k^{-\frac 1 2}$$

so that:

$$ \omega(k) = \sqrt n k^{\frac 1 2}$$

Then:

$$ v_g = \frac{d\omega}{dk}=\frac 1 2 \sqrt n k^{-\frac 1 2} = \frac 1 2 v_p$$

That's a deep water gravity wave. A simplified versions (2 frequencies) looks like this:

[image]

Red square (green circle) moves at the phase (group) velocity.

Comment: First of all, the graph is beautiful thank you!  How did you generate it?

Comment: Then why is my first method giving wrong answer?